# Formatting an internal HDD on PC with no optical drive

Tags: formatting, usb-boot

How can I format the internal HDD of a PC that has no optical drive, only USB? I'm guessing some sort of USB bootable option, I'm just not quite sure what? Disconnecting the HDD from the PC and attaching it to another PC is not an option at this point, so I'm counting on a software solution. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you only mention formatting it, use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) in a USB.  Or any Live Linux on a USB you can use GParted or Parted or Fdisk.